# How can I submit radio buttons answer in database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

This is the code I have written:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form action="db.php" method="post">

YES:<input type="radio" name="YES" value="YES">

NO:<input type="radio"  name="NO"  value="NO" >

<input type="submit" name="submit value="submit">
</form>

</body>
<html>
```

**db.php**

```
<?php

    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','my user id','my password');
    if(!con)
    { echo 'not connected to server';}else { echo 'something else is wrong' ;}

    if(!mysqli_select_db($con,'my user id')
    { echo 'Database error selection';}

    $YES = $_POST['YES'];
    $NO = $_POST['NO'];

    $sql = INSERT INTO users (YES,NO) VALUES ('$YES','$NO');

    if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    { echo 'Answer not submitted please try again!!!!!!!!';}
    else{
    echo 'Your answer successfully submitted \n Thanks for participating';}

    header(" refresh:2; url=index.html");

?>
```

---

There is something wrong in it.
Can anyone please tell what is wrong?

Note: If 2 users submit YES then in database YES would get int value as 2
If 1 users submit NO then in database NO would get int value as 1.

Comment: What's exactly wrong with it? Aside from not closing this attribute `name="submit"`

Comment: first of all, you have to give same name to both of radio button in input, also for reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868935/adding-radio-button-values-to-mysql-table-using-php

Comment: And your radio buttons might as well be checkboxes since selecting one won't deselect the other. and you don't associate a numeric value to them anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You are using radio button the wrong way. Radio button should have the same 'name'. In your case you may use name="yesno".

```html
 YES:<input type="radio" name="yesorno" value="yes">
 NO:<input type="radio" name="yesorno" value="no">
```

For your PHP it should be like this.

```html
 <?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 $yesorno=$_POST['yesno'];
  $sql = INSERT INTO users (columnName) VALUES ('$yesorno');
  mysqli_query($con,$sql); // Execute query
}
?>
```

**And please express your goal as clear as possible. For now i pinpointed what is wrong on your coding semantics.**

Comment: I want the answer to be submitted in database, in such a way so I can understand how many people had submitted the amswer as "YES"  and how many submitted the answer as "NO".        Forgot about my codes which I had written can u give me the new from scratch

Comment: Then save their answers as I written. Then in a new Query SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE columnName='YES'; You have to write different scripts.

Comment: Can u explain it more clearly by giving it in a code format. I am unable to understand what are you trying to say

Comment: Please give me the database SQL also (the code I had to write to make the table).....

Comment: @rohitsingh I think you should open a new question for that. But, if you would browse for more answers here in stackoverflow, I am sure you'll find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Above looks good. Another way is to add a label:

```
<label for="yesorno">Question:</label>
<input type="radio" name="yesorno" value="yes">YES:
<input type="radio" name="yesorno" value="no">NO:<br />
```